# sending Activity datapoints list by opengraph Facebook via Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fitnesse

I am working on an android fitness application, I am able to send to facebook course details like distance, duration, or calories through my android application, but I cannot send datapoints list of locations to draw a map on my timeline status, I used the following code for this purpose:

```
public void shareWorkout (View v)
{
    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) 
    {
        OpenGraphObject course = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost(null);
        course.setType("fitness.course");
        course.setTitle("Walking Course");
        course.setUrl("http://samples.ogp.me/136756249803614");
        course.setDescription("walked a course");

        course.getData().setProperty("distance:value", 2.5f);
        course.getData().setProperty("distance:units", "km");
        course.getData().setProperty("duration:value", 1800.0f);
        course.getData().setProperty("duration:units", "s");
        course.getData().setProperty("speed:value", 3.0f);
        course.getData().setProperty("speed:units", "m/s");

        int[] cals = {50,70};

        course.getData().setProperty("metrics:calories",cals);

        OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
        action.setProperty("course", course);

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "fitness.walks", "course").build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    }

}
```

After running this code I got the exception:

```
com.facebook.facebookexception: failed to generate preview for user.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're setting the data properties wrong.

For example, "distance" should be another GraphObject with "value" and "unit" properties:

```
GraphObject distance = new GraphObject.Factory.create();
distance.setProperty("value", 2.5f);
distance.setProperty("units", "km");
course.getData.setProperty("distance", distance);
```

Similarly for duration and speed. Lastly, "metrics" takes in a list of graph objects, so you need to construct a list of GraphObjects first, then set it for the "metrics" property on getData.

Comment: how to display data poiunts location using metrics and location properties